# Returning a Razor (cshtml) page from an IHttpHandler without redirection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ihttphandler

I have got an ASP.net MVC project and admittedly I'm not too interested in the way MS implements MVC and so have stripped the project to the very bare minimum. I don't have any routes defined and instead have a `DefaultDocument` entry in `web.config` that points to a class that implements `IHttpHandler`.

From my `IHttpHandler` class, I'm wanting to output a Razor .cshtml file, I do not wish to create route entries to the cshtml files and so I cannot simply redirect the user to the .cshtml file. I've found a number of resources talking about `PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance` but this appears to be aimed at aspx files rather than the Razor View Engine.

So, what classes should be of interest to me in outputting a .cshtml file to the `HttpContext`  from my `IHttpHandler` class?

```
public class Main : IHttpHandler{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context){
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears I have been looking for the wrong thing - the secret phrase is:

*Rendering razor view to a string*

The code below works quite well it would seem:

```
public static string GetRazorViewAsString(object model, string filePath)
{
    var st = new StringWriter();
    var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(context, routeData), new FakeController());
    var razor = new RazorView(controllerContext, filePath, null, false, null);
    razor.Render(new ViewContext(controllerContext, razor, new ViewDataDictionary(model), new TempDataDictionary(), st), st);
    return st.ToString();
}
```

Code from http://forums.asp.net/post/5333141.aspx